# <img> tag and JSP

Tags: sql, jsp, image

All of my images are stored in a directory, "/Images"
and the filenames are stored in a sql table.

I want iterate through the images, and display them in a table

//for every product

```
<table>
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
<tr>
<th> Product Name </th> <th> image </th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> ${product.name} </td>
<td><img src="Images/" + ${product.image}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<table>
```

This approach is wrong, but i am using it to show what i intend to do.

Comment: i managed to solve my problem. mods please close this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take this

```
<img src="images/<%=rs.getString(1)=%>" />
```

use jsp tag <%= %> to write java expression.

bye